# javascript: click event listener is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

I have attach a event listener when someone clicks on the map marker.

the event triggered without any problem on pc view. but on mobile event is not triggered.

here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('leaderboard__profile')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('ashik');
  }
})
```

and this is the deployed version

```
https://142.44.240.91
```

Comment: Hi, you can not "click" on a mobile device hence the absence of support for click events. For Mobile devices see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: i have tried this


document.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('leaderboard__profile')) {
    console.log('hello')
    e.target.classList.toggle('ashik');
  }
})
but didn't work

Comment: Class list gives the classes of an element. You are attaching the event listener to document which can not be assigned any class. For the above example to work the event listener should be attached to some element in the document body that might have the mentioned class.